# How to plot a custom spectrogram using pcolormesh

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

**I have:**

- 1D vector containing hourly start times:

  - `>> timez=np.arange(0, 84600, 3600)`
  - `>> timez.shape`: `(24,)`
- 1D vector containing frequency values from 0.5 to 50Hz:

  - `>> len(freqs)`: `70200`
  - `>> freqs.shape`: `(70200,)`
- 2D array containing `24` rows corresponding to the **24 start times** of `70200` amplitude values that correspond to the **70200 values of the frequency vector**

  - `>> data.shape`: `(24, 70200)`
  - `>> len(data)`: `24`
  - `>> len(data[0]`: `70200`

So, `data[0]` maps to `timez[0]`, `data[1]` to `timez[1]`, etc. and the frequency values in `freqs` map to the amplitude values in each `data` row.

**I've tried:**

```
fig, axes=plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9), nrows=2, ncols=1)

axes[1].pcolormesh(timez, freqs, data, shading='auto')
```

**Gives error**:

`TypeError: Dimensions of C (24, 70200) are incompatible with X (24) and/or Y (70200); see help(pcolormesh)`

**I've reviewed**:

[pcolormesh tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolormesh-levels-py)

- Which lead me to set `shading='auto'`

And, [pcolormesh documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh)

- Which I'm confused by because it states that the data vector should be a 2D array, which it is.

Do I need to alter my data structures to fit into `pcolormesh` ? Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: Did you try swapping x and y? E.g. by transposing your data? `pcolormesh(timez, freqs, hvsr.T, shading='auto')`. Also, the prefered size of x and y is one more than the dimensions of the 2D data. E.g. `timez = np.arange(0, 84601, 3600)` and `freqs.shape: (70201,)`.  A pcolormesh creates rectangles between the coordinates given by x and y. You need 25 boundaries to get 24 regions.  If they are only one off, `pcolormesh` silently drops one row and/or one column.

Comment: @JohanC That worked! Thanks. Why do the data need be transposed??